# How do I get jQuery colorbox modules to work within a flexigrid?

Tags: php, jquery, json, colorbox, flexigrid

I'm using flexigrid to display incoming leads in our CRM.  Within the rows of incoming leads, I've added links for "View Contacts" and "View Notes".  I'm trying to get these links to open in a colorbox module when clicked. They currently opening in a new window when clicked.

**HTML/Flexigrid Code:**

```
<div id="flex"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(e){      
    $(".merchant_add_note").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"}); 
    $(".merchant_add_contact").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"}); 
    $(".merchant_view_notes").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"});   
    $(".merchant_view_contacts").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"}); 

    $("#flex").flexigrid({
        url: '/rep/get_leads',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        colModel : [
            {display: 'Merchant', name : 'merchant_name', width : 220, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Date Added', name : 'merchant_created', width : 150, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Last Contacted', name : 'merchant_last_contacted', width : 150, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Contact', name : 'merchant_contacts', width : 180, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Notes', name : 'merchant_notes', width : 160, sortable : false, align: 'left'}
            ],      
        sortname: "merchant_name",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: false,
        useRp: false,
        rp: 50,
        width: 950,
        height: 500
    });   

});
</script>
```

**/rep/get_leads json array:**

```
function get_leads(){
    $args = array(
        'id' => $this->session->userdata('rep_id'),
        'sort' => $_REQUEST['sortname'],
        'sortorder' => $_REQUEST['sortorder']
    );
    $leads = $this->reps->leads($args);

    foreach($leads as $lead){
        $row['id'] = $lead['merchant_id'];
        $row['cell'] = array(
            'merchant_name' => '<a href="/rep/merchant/'.$lead['merchant_id'].'">'.$lead['merchant_name'].'</a>',
            'merchant_created' => $lead['merchant_created'],
            'merchant_last_contacted' => $lead['merchant_last_contacted'],
            'merchant_contacts' => '<a href="/rep/merchant_contacts/'.$lead['merchant_id'].'" class="small_blue merchant_view_contacts">View</a> - <a href="/rep/merchant_add_contact/'.$lead['merchant_id'].'" class="small_blue merchant_add_contact">Add</a>',
            'merchant_notes' => '<a href="/rep/merchant_notes/'.$lead['merchant_id'].'" class="small_blue merchant_view_notes">View</a> - <a href="/rep/merchant_add_note/'.$lead['merchant_id'].'" class="small_blue merchant_add_note">Add</a>'
        );
        $array[] = $row;
    }   
    $data['rows'] = $array;
    print json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to use onSuccess:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(e){      
    $("#flex").flexigrid({
        url: '/rep/get_leads',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        colModel : [
            {display: 'Merchant', name : 'merchant_name', width : 370, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Date Added', name : 'merchant_created', width : 150, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Last Contacted', name : 'merchant_last_contacted', width : 150, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Contacts', name : 'merchant_contacts', width : 100, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Notes', name : 'merchant_notes', width : 100, sortable : false, align: 'left'}
            ],  
        searchitems : [
            {display: 'Merchant', name : 'merchant_name', isdefault: true}
            ],
        sortname: "merchant_name",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        useRp: false,
        title: 'Your Leads',
        rp: 500,
        width: 950,
        height: 650,
        onSuccess: function() { 
            $(".merchant_add_note").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"}); 
            $(".merchant_add_contact").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"}); 
            $(".merchant_view_notes").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"});   
            $(".merchant_view_contacts").colorbox({width:"750px", overlayClose:false, height:"400px", transition:"none"}); 
        } 
    });  
});
</script>
```